# add a block of related products to any search result item

Tags: search, views

What I want is , when a user searches for a special product , for each single search result a block of similar products show up (containing products image and product title as images alt).

I do have a taxonomy vocabulary called usability with terms gaming , light weight and ... ,

so if a search result is of kind product , the block of related products should be seen under it

So my questions are :

1. how to alter search result view so I can place my block
2. how can I fetch data of an result item to pass it to view filter

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: @Geoff sorry I edited my question

Comment: What is the search engine? The drupal default sezrch form or Views module sesrch?

Comment: @Drupalist the search engine is drupal core search

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do with a combination of these:

[Views Field View Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

and

[Views Related Content Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_related_content)

> Views Related Content is an extension to the Views module. It helps
>   show the related contents, related nodes on the content detail page.
>   This module makes it easy for you to work with contents, nodes by
>   adding the filter criteria by Author, Content Type, Taxonomy Terms in
>   the Views configuration.

Adding the related content view as a field in the primary view should show the results for each row. Exactly how to integrate them depends on your set up.

Comment: These modules description made me confused , but I will try it , thanks for help , do you introduce any help for these modules? tutorial or ...

Comment: @Drupars have only used the Views Field View module, and the README explains everything farely well - you'll have to search for the other one if the documentation with it is insufficient

Comment: I read the Readme and it helps , of course I think this will not work for search results cause they are not outputted as views but I found this module useful and thanks for help

Comment: I wanted to vote your answer up but it said I need to have 15 reputation , I will do that whenever I reached that reputation

Comment: you tagged the question with Views and Search-Views, so I assumed you wanted a Views answer